# Two SDL Windows. How to know which was clicked in SDL_Event?

Tags: sdl

I have two different SDL windows simultaneously in one application. How do I know which of them was clicked when I get a mousebutton event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a data field named "windowID" into SDL_MouseButtonEvent, you can know which window catched that event with that. For more info : http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MouseButtonEvent